# Can we use React Native version of the SDK for Mobilepush?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, sdk

We're using an iOS and Android app with Mobilepush. The Engineering team has already built the app code in React native version. If they use the react native version of the sdk would they get same feature parity as the android and iOS sdk's? Will really appreciate any insight.

Best,
Monomit

Answer (score 1):

Please see [Android Hybrid Mobile Apps](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/#hybrid-mobile-apps) and [iOS Hybrid Mobile Apps](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/#hybrid-mobile-apps) on the homepage of the documentation site for the push SDKs.

Will you have parity with native applications?  No.  Inbox, Geofence & Beacon messaging have not been implemented within the plugins, however, they source for the plugins is available (see the docs).  Feel free to fork the plugins and extend them as your needs require.